# create a InApp browser implementation in iOS app

Tags: uiwebview, iphone-5, ios7

I have a requirement were in i have to create a view to display webpages with back, forward and refresh button in iOS app.
how to implement this functionality?

Comment: You can use Kendo UI mobile - a Javascript and HTML5 framework, which allow you to create native looking apps for several mobile platforms including iOS. link: http://www.kendoui.com/mobile.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIWebView`.
Set the delegate to the view controller.

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

Other remarkable properties,

```
self.webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
```

To load a URLRequest,

```
[self.webView loadRequest:theRequest];
```

or for only strings, use

```
[self.webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];
```

And some delegates here. web view has its own history, you can use it by calling its back and forward methods.

```
#pragma mark - UIWebView delegate

// You can handle your own url scheme or let the web view handle it.
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
        navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    NSLog(@"url=%@, %@, %@",
          request.URL, request.URL.query, request.URL.host);

    if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked) {     
        if ([request.URL.scheme compare:@"customescheme"] == NSOrderedSame) {
            if ([request.URL.host compare:kSomethingDotCom] == NSOrderedSame) {
                [self mymethod];
            } else if ([request.URL.host compare:kAnotherDotCom] == NSOrderedSame) {
                [self method2];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Unsupported service.");
            }
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}

- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)webView didFailLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [Resources showAlert:@"Could not load." withTitle:@"Error!"];
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

#pragma mark - Actions

- (IBAction)didPressBackButton:(id)sender
{
    [_webView goBack];
}

- (IBAction)didPressForwardButton:(id)sender
{
    [_webView goForward];
}
```

Similarly you can have the stop method. To refresh reload the request again. Before going back or forward you can check the methods canGoBack or canGoForward. 
See docs at, http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Great answer, I implemented the first 2 methods from UIWebViewDelegate, but nothing happens, these methods don't get called (I do have a hyperlink in index.html), do you know why?

Comment: Did you set the delegate, self.webView.delegate = self; or something like this...

Answer (score 0):

It is a piece of cake, all you need is UIWebview component and its delegates and you need to create a custom navigation bar that is it.